# Multiple setState using useState but trigger only once?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect, use-state

```
 import "./styles.css";
 import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

 export default function App() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
   useEffect(() => {
    console.warn("render");
   });
  function btnClick() {
     setCount(count + 1);
     setCount(count + 1);
  }

return (
<div className="App">
  {count}
  <button onClick={btnClick}>Click Me</button>
</div>
);
}
```

Button Click only increase by 1, not by 2 and also render once.Any specific behaviour of useState?

Comment: use the functor syntax: `setCount(count + 1);` becomes `setCount(prev => prev + 1);`

Answer (score 4):

This is because both `setCount` read the same value (in a single render cycle) and the results the same value (Actually, react batch the two updates to a single update and ignores the second update as it is the same as the output of the first update).

To guarantee to get the updated value use the callback updater function with `setCount` (These updates are also batched to a single update to optimize the rendering but give the correct incremented value - meaning that react does increment twice the value first and set that value to avoid two renders).

```
function btnClick() {
    setCount((prevCount) => prevCount + 1);
    setCount((prevCount) => prevCount + 1);
}
```

[Code Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/festive-banach-ziz8y?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: right conclusion but wrong reason. `count` is declared as a `const` and cannot be mutated(get new value) on it's own, in the same render run. It's just not how Javascript works. Only on next render run(which happens shortly after a call to `setCount`) new value will be assigned in `const [count, setCount] = useState(...)` line. With that, calling `setCount(count + 1)` twice is literally calling setter twice with the same value.

Comment: @skyboyer, By the first time `setCount(count + 1)` update the value and rerender will happen with count incremented. And by the second call `setCount(count + 1)` which also read a stale value from the first render cycle. And react even ignore second update since it's the same as the current value. But with the callback it gets the current state value.

Comment: each `setCount(count + 1)` instructs relevant `useState()` like "next time you're asked, return this value instead of current". And it does not affect what is assigned to `const counter` at current moment.

Comment: why am I nit-picking here? because the difference is really important. If "setState is async" was main reason then with using external sources(say, Redux `useSelector` + `useDispatch`) it was not important at all. But understanding this thing with `const` and (re)assigning _is_ important.

Comment: let's break some React rules on mutating data directly. `const a = { val: 1 }; setCounter(a.val++); setCounter(a.val++);` would rerender value updated by 2, not by 1. And it's not because `setCounter` became sync, no.

Comment: Yes you are right. even `setCounter` was sync issue will still be there. It's all about the how we provide value to `setCounter`. either direct value or callback.

Comment: useState work asynchrously, so whe updating the value by setCount(count+1) it will not update immdieate. it need callback function to update immdieatly.  setCount((prevCount) => prevCount + 1);